# Node.js path.normalize() nodule corrupts Amazon S3 urls

Tags: node.js

When I try

```
path.normalize('http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/idelog/token_page_images/8cbf37c0-63e5-11e4-a43e-978e01bbbad9_page.png/');
```

This is incorrectly parsed as:

> 'http:/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/idelog/token_page_images/8cbf37c0-63e5-11e4-a43e-978e01bbbad9_page.png/'

Note the single slash. Anyone know if there is a fix for path.normalize()?

Comment: Because a URL isn't a path. What are you actually trying to do by passing this path through `.normalize`?

Comment: Ahhhh, wow, that is dumb of me. That explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood that protocol is not part of a path.